# Bad File Number error code in linux read syscall

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am new to assembly and trying to make a function that prints a file to stdout.

After the first iteration, it reads and prints 100 bytes succesfully. When it loops again after that, the read syscall throws a -9 error code (Or a bad file number error)

```
prtopenf:

section .data
   .bufsize dq 100

section .bss
   .buffer resd 1
   .FD     resd 1

section .text
; rdi is argument FD

push rbp
mov rbp, rsp

mov [.FD], rdi  ; save local file descriptor

; seek beginning of the file
mov rax, 8          ; file lseek
mov rdi, [.FD]
mov rsi, 0  ; begin of file 
syscall

; keep printing until call returns 0 read
.prtloop:
; read buffer
   xor rax, rax
   mov rdi, [.FD]
   mov rsi, .buffer
   mov rdx, [.bufsize]
   syscall

; look for errors or end of file
   cmp rax, 0
   jl .readerror
   je .done
   
; write buffer
   mov rax, 1          ; write
   mov rdi, 1          ; stdout file descriptor
   mov rsi, .buffer    ; buffer memory address
   mov rdx, [.bufsize] ; size of buffer
   syscall

   jmp .prtloop

.readerror:
   mov rsp, rbp
   pop rbp

   ret

.done:
   mov rsp, rbp
   pop rbp

   ret
```

Comment: You are reserving only 4 bytes for each of `.buffer` and `.FD`.  But `.FD` is an 8 byte value and buffer is supposed to be 100 bytes long.  How comes the mismatch?

Comment: Would this be a solution? .buffer resb 100
 .FD  resb 8

Comment: yes, that should solve at least this part of your problem.

Comment: Wich other part is there?

Comment: I think your program lacks an `exit` system call.

Comment: A file descriptor is an `int`; it's pointless to store/reload a full 8 bytes instead of just 4.  Read the man page (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and choose operand-size accordingly.  Although the calling convention allows high garbage, so the kernel should be ignoring garbage in the high bytes. So yes that's a bug, but since `.FD` is the last thing in your `.bss`, you're not stepping on anything else so it's probably harmless in this specific.  (But still worth pointing out, @fuz). Also use `strace ./a.out` to see what system calls you actually make, with args decoded.

Comment: Yeah, I ran this with strace and got `read(681572, 0x402008, 100)             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)` . That FD is `0xa6664`, i.e. a few bytes of garbage I typed, ending with newline.  (The lseek failed with -EISPIPE, the first read on `fd=0` succeeded.  RDI was `0` on entry to this because I built it into a static executable, and Linux happens to zero the regs.)

Comment: Oh right, the problem is your `.buffer` only had space for 4 bytes, so of course `read` overwrote into the `resd 1` space for the fd.  IDK why you're keeping FD in memory at all; R8, R9, and R10 are free.